# Paypal automatic payment Deductions

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-subscriptions

In my app i want to add pay with paypal option.but i want, once the user added(integrated) thier paypal account to my app ,they does not need to authorize payments.All payments get automaticaly deducted from the users paypal account

So ,Is this possible that i can check the balance in the Paypal customer's account and capture it too without user consent and also charge the customer with his consent.(Same happens in case of deduction in credit cards for uber)

Comment: There is no single short answer to this. As a general rule, PayPal protects it's accountholders from anyone who wants to "check the balance ... and  capture it too without user consent." However, they have a variety of products that offer sellers the ability to collect permission from users for future payments, called Subscriptions, Reference Transactions, Billing Agreements, Future Payments, etc. There is also a GetBalance API. However, many of these products have some vetting restrictions (ie PayPal restricts their use). Read some of the docs then contact PayPal.

Comment: thanks @geewiz. Actually paypal has extensive set of methods which confussesd me.your answer restrict my  search space. Thanks

Comment: You are not alone. PayPal has been in business for almost 15 years, with all the changes that have come and gone in the web in that time, and never wants to deprecate products because people are relying on them for their businesses. So by now they have WAY too many products.... definitely makes things confusing. Good luck.

Comment: Its very difficult for beginners like me to efficenlty implement paypal with so much confusion arround.But thanks alot